# Laravel - two registration form with auth system

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I would like to know how it is the best way to create two register forms in Laravel 5.2. I am using the auth system. I don't want to use two different controllers.

The first registration form is for registering to the application I am developing. The second one is for user registered by each application owner.

I was thinking about something like this inside the AuthController, but I am not very convinced:

```
public function getRegister() {
    if(something){
       //show the form 1
    }else{
       //show the form 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the issue exactly. Are you trying to perform some team structure?

Comment: It is a accounting/Scheduler system for private teacher. The first form is for the teacher who wants to use the application, the second one for parents and student for using the teacher's services through the application.

Comment: You do not need two different controllers, but I would prefer two different actions and different forms in that case. That's easier, especially the end user will choose to register as Teacher or Student.

Comment: That is the problem: same controller for two forms. I would prefer to have the main form for the teacher and the other inside the scheduler site. I would like to use the auth system for both. I could add the parent/student easily as new Model, but I think it is better to use the auth system for both

Comment: You will use the same auth system, and everything will remain the same. Just the form the action that registers the user will be different

Comment: @J03Bukowski how would you know which form to show ?

Comment: @J03Bukowski and why you don't want to use 2 different controllers ? Is it because of authentication ? I mean you want multi-Auth ?

Comment: @jaysingkar I am using two user tables: one for the admins' application and one for the students and parents

Comment: ok.. so the 2 forms in controller are for students and parents respectively ?

Comment: or for admin and (student and parent)

Comment: one is the main registration form (for the "admin") in order to create the account, the other one is to register the parent and student through the admin's application. It is similar to an admin and team application.

Comment: @J03Bukowski that means parents or students can't register themselves. right ?sorry I'm just trying to understand ur requirements

Comment: @jaysingkar don't worry. I appreciate your help. I am not sure about this right now. I don't think this could change the coding so much. To be more clear, have you ever used accounting or scheduler online service or booking service? You register for having your account andyou or a customer can register to your account for using your account services. Example: booking lessons, see the invoices, etc.

Comment: In this case I would suggest to keep the form controllers separate, this would make your code easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

By default the AuthController uses the **RegistesrUsers** trait. It has the function **getRegister**.

It is linked to Route

```
Route::get('auth/register', AuthController@getRegister);
```

Default getRegister function

```
/**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getRegister()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}
```

Override the function in AuthController

```
public function getRegister()
{
    if(condition){
        return view('view1');
    }else{
        return view('view2');
    }
}
```

This will help you to keep the code in the **AuthController**.